# Type conversion conflict with generic protocols in swift?

Tags: swift, generics, types, protocols

Im having trouble resolving a type conflict in swift with generics (and generic protocols). I keep getting this error when attempting to call a class function within an operator function.

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Chain<Initial, E.Initial, E>'to expected argument of type 'Chain<Initial, E.Initial, E>'
```

Below is the operator function signature and body. The error is being declared as a type problem of providing 'c' to the class function.

```
public func +<Initial, E : Bindable>(c: Chain<Initial, E.Initial, E>, e: E) -> Chain<Initial, E.Result, E> {
return Chain.append(chain: c, element: e)
}
```

The function signature (identical to the operator function signature) of the Chain class append function is;

```
static func append<Initial, E : Bindable>(chain : Chain<Initial, E.Initial, E>, element: E) -> Chain<Initial, E.Result, E>
```

And the Bindable protocol is declared as;

```
public protocol Bindable {
    associatedtype Initial 
    associatedtype Result
}
```

The types are identical, the operator is just syntactic sugar for the static class function. Am I improperly using generic protocols? Or is this a type system bug? Where I am just going to have to copy over the class function code into the operator code?

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question: I just needed to provide a type signature for the class function call, Chain.append(chain: c, element: e).

This resolved the problem by providing context to the method call. Before it did not know what type it should be returning.